# Create iterator for multimap

Tags: c++, iterator, multimap

I have this code

```
class Iterator{
private:
  MultiMap mp;
  int curent;
public:
  Iterator(MultiMap md):mp(md),curent(0){};
};


class MultiMap{
private:
  int m;
  int urm[20];
public:
  Iterator begin(){return Iterator();/*here is the probleme*/};
};
```

How can i create iterator for begin from class MultiMap?
How i should call Iterator creator from method begin?

Comment: Hint: `Iterator` takes a `MultiMap` as argument.

Comment: i know but, how can i use my class as argument?

Comment: Using the `this` pointer.

Comment: thanks, so i changed, from `Iterator` private: `MultiMap *mp`;